# How to write condition "x = y" such that it is true when both x and y are NULL?

Tags: sql, join, null

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT tblTxn.Currency, tblTxn.Amount, tblTxn.Desc, tblAccounts.Account, tblTxn.Type
FROM tblAccounts
    INNER JOIN tblTxn ON (tblAccounts.Currency = tblTxn.Currency)
WHERE
    tblTxn.Type=tblAccounts.Type OR 
    (tblAccounts.Type Is Null And tblAccounts.Type Is Null);
```

Here `tblTxn.Type` and `tblAccounts.Type` can have values or null values.
I need both to match. Null values are showing expected result but values aren't.

How to fix this?

---

I was using the query in MS Access 2007. From the below solutions I adjusted the query like:

```
SELECT tblTxn.Currency, tblTxn.Amount, tblTxn.Desc, tblAccounts.Account, tblTxn.Type FROM tblAccounts INNER JOIN tblTxn ON tblAccounts.Currency = tblTxn.Currency WHERE Nz(tblTxn.Type,0) = Nz(tblAccounts.Type,0)
```

It is showing the expected result now. **Thanks for excellent support.**
NB.(Function **Nz(Value, [ValueIfNull])** is COALESCE alternative in Access.)

One thing I would like to know, if I use `WHERE  tblTxn.Type=tblAccounts.Type OR Nz(tblTxn.Type,0) = Nz(tblAccounts.Type,0)`, it shows the same result. How did your query worked with non-null values while you were matching null values only?

Comment: This is almost correct. See Alex's answer where he points out that `tblAccounts.Type` is checked for NULL ... twice. This is likely an error.

Comment: There is a `distinct from` predicate which might eventually make it in T-SQL: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use IsNull to check for null values.

See MSDN: [ISNULL (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) (assuming SQL Server)

Not sure if this will exactly meet your requirement - but should point you to right direction.

```
SELECT  tblTxn.Currency, 
    tblTxn.Amount, 
    tblTxn.Desc, 
    tblAccounts.Account, 
    tblTxn.Type 
FROM    tblAccounts 
        INNER JOIN tblTxn ON (tblAccounts.Currency = tblTxn.Currency) 
WHERE   IsNull(tblTxn.Type, '') =IsNull(tblAccounts.Type,'') 
    OR COALESCE(tblAccounts.Type, tblAccounts.Type) Is Null;
```

Comment: I think [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) is more common (or at least, more [widely](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) [supported](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php))

Comment: @BlueRaja - Yes you are right that would be good for second part. But IsNull would be required for checking the first part.

Comment: coalesce is faster but also requires the types to match. isnull allows you to return a different type like a string instead of an int. in this scenario doesn't matter but kind of interesting

Comment: +1 For pointing out only a single `COALESCE` is required, which is neat. However, almost +0 for the `IsNull` stuff above which is not needed (and will introduce false positives for blank fields). `IsNull` isn't required because if either field is a `NULL` they are not `=` *and* if both fields are `NULL` then the `COALESCE() IS NULL` catches it in the `OR`.

Comment: @pst - what about none of the fields are null and have same value? IsNull would take care of that. Agree with the false positive point though. Would be interesting to see a solution that removes a false positive.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser If neither x *nor* y is `NULL` and the value is the same, then `x = y` is true. The only "fun" case of `=` is when x *and* y are NULL as `NULL = NULL` is false; the COALESCE handles this. The ISNULL above will *actually prevent* the COALESCE above from ever running for something that *would* match (and it introduces false positives for empty '' fields -- see Alex's answer). Run through the truth-table.

Comment: Cases argued: `ISNULL(x,'') = ISNULL(y,'')` -- True when both x and y are `NULL` (both coerced to '') or when `x = y` is true (neither is NULL) or when one is '' and one is `NULL` (false positive from coercion to ''). `COALESCE(x,y) IS NULL` -- True if and only if both x and y are `NULL` (if either is non-`NULL` the return will be non-`NULL` and thus the expression will be false). Since `COALESCE` will handle the case "when both are NULL" then `x = y` will adequate handle the case when "they are equals, but not NULL".

Comment: If either of x or y is null, then x=y does not return true / false, it returns unknown. Hence IsNull (or collace) is required for making a comparison.See [MSDN: NULL Comparison Search Conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196339(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: I was wrong above about using `FALSE` above -- I have corrected it to only point out the cases of being `TRUE`. `UNKNOWN OR TRUE` is `TRUE` and `TRUE OR DONTCARE` is `TRUE`.

Comment: I am arguing that the nice use of `COALESCE` is enough and that: `tblTxn.Type = tblAccounts.Type OR COALESCE(tblAccounts.Type, tblAccounts.Type) IS NULL` is sufficient and false-positive free :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your query checks `tblAccounts.Type Is Null` twice. The query would work if you replace one `tblAccounts.Type Is Null` condition with `tblTxn.Type Is Null`.

Also you could do:

```
DECLARE @FakeString VARCHAR(10)
SET @FakeString = '!@#$%^&'

SELECT tblTxn.Currency, tblTxn.Amount, tblTxn.Desc, tblAccounts.Account, tblTxn.Type
FROM tblAccounts 
    INNER JOIN tblTxn ON tblAccounts.Currency = tblTxn.Currency
WHERE 
    ISNULL(tblTxn.Type, @FakeString) = ISNULL(tblAccounts.Type, @FakeString)
```

If value is integer, you could do something like this

```
DECLARE @FakeType INT
SET @FakeType = -9999
```

Comment: +1 For pointing out the error with the original. I would use the first "explicit" approach with the correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tblTxn.Currency
, tblTxn.Amount
, tblTxn.Desc
, tblAccounts.Account
, tblTxn.Type
FROM tblAccounts
INNER JOIN tblTxn ON tblAccounts.Currency = tblTxn.Currency
WHERE ISNULL(tblTxn.Type,'') = ISNULL(tblAccounts.Type,'')
--  This works as well
--  WHERE COALESCE(tblTxn.Type,'') = COALESCE(tblAccounts.Type,'')
```

Using the `ISNULL` and returning the empty string will let your keys that are NULL be matched.  The danger there is that you will likely have more matches than are really relevant.  But, the query provided should suit you either way.